# I am developing newsletter in php with cron job apps. pls but getting problem with php code for date and time

Tags: php

I am developing newsletter in php with cron job apps. pls but getting problem with php code for date and time

any body have any good reference pls tell me

Comment: @ravindrasingh22 Please post any error messages, along with the relevant code for your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this [reference](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/introducing-cron).

Comment: which referece. i m want auto schedule of newslatter in php